# Let $g \in S_n$ then how to compute $g(1,2,\dots, m)g^{-1}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

For all $g \in S_n$ with $m\leq n$, where $S_n$ is the permutation group,  i want to compute 
\begin{align}
g (1,2, \dots, m) g^{-1} = ???
\end{align}
explicitly.

For $n=3$, with $g=(1,2)$ i have

\begin{align}
(1,2) (1,2,3) (1,2)^{-1} 
= (1,2) (1,2,3)(2,1) = (1,3,2)
\end{align}

I want to generalized this into above case.

Is there any good idea?

Comment: The result is just $(g(1)\, g(2)\,\ldots\, g(m))$, you can verify this by proving it for cycles then writing an arbitrary permutation as a product of disjoint cycles.

Comment: @AdamHughes: How can i prove this? just by plugging arbitrary cycles?

Comment: By doing the computation, yes:  It's not hard, you need only see where a single element goes since it is arbitrary

Comment: @AdamHughes: Two elements, actually: One that is the image of something in the cycle, and one that isn't.

Comment: @HenningMakholm ah yes, good catch!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any cycle $(a_1\;a_2\;\ldots\;a_k)$ you have
$$ g(a_1\;a_2\;\ldots\;a_k)g^{-1} = (g(a_1)\;g(a_2)\;\ldots\;g(a_k)) $$
Since conjugation is a homomorphism, you can apply this to each of the cycles in the permutation you're looking at.